# How to Initialize object by different properties?

Tags: php, oop

There is an object, which can be initialized by id or by name.

How it should be handled?

```
class user
{
    function __construct($id_or_name)
    {
        if ( is_numeric($id_or_name) )
        {
            $this->id = $id_or_name;
            $this->populate_by_id($this->id)
        }
        else
        {
            $this->name = $id_or_name;
            $this->populate_by_name($this->name)
        }
    }
    ...
}

$user1 = new user('Max');
$user2 = new user(123);
```

Is it ok for general practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's terrible. Introuce two static "fabric methods", one receive `string`, other - `integer`. And construct your object differently:

```
class user
{
    //you might want make it private
    function __construct($id_or_name)
    {
        //common logic
    }

    static function construct_by_name($name){
        $result = new self();
        $result->name = $name; //note you are in the same class, so you may directly assign private variables
        $result ->populate_by_name($result ->name);
        return $result;
    }

    static function construct_by_id($id){
        $result = new self();
        $result->id= $id; //note you are in the same class, so you may directly assign private variables
        $result ->populate_by_id($result ->id);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to post the same. +1

Comment: You are missing argument in `new self()` and forgot to return created instance. Also, you shouldn't use `$this->` in static context.

Comment: this is equally terrible. the ctor should not have "common logic". It should only assign values and not do work. Static factory methods on a domain object violate SRP for that class. Put them in a factory.

Comment: @Gordon, following your logic, ctors violate SRP too. So, if there is a factory already - that's right, those methods belongs to factory. But if there isn't, I don't think it's good idea to create one. This way the class is a factory for itself. By common logic I mean setting fields, acquiring resources and other actions **common** for both creation methods.

Comment: @J0Hn No, that's not following my logic. That's following your assumption about what should be in a ctor ;) A ctor doesnt violate SRP if you [dont do work in it](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Ctors can initialize, but they shouldnt create.

Comment: @Gordon, I have read that article. Well, there is a sense in it, but no single word about having "fabric methods" inside the class violates SRP. It's all about doing some work in ctor. I agree with you in that ctors should contain only initialization logic, but we are discussing is it OK to place fabric methods inside the fabricated class, aren't we? :). Btw, my code fits the design described in the article much better, than original. :)

Comment: @J0HN no, that wasnt your argument. You claimed ctors *in general* violate SRP, which isnt true. They only do when you put creational logic (your "common logic") into them. The article explains these things. As for the static factory methods: SRP is defined as "an object should have only one reason to change". When you put business logic *and* creation logic onto the object, that's two reasons. The article states: "Object graph creation is a full fledged responsibility", hence having factory methods on a business object violates SRP.

Comment: In addition, having static methods will lead to undesired high coupling with collaborators. [Avoid static methods](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html). If you use a factory, you will have none of these drawbacks.

Comment: @Gordon, just a quotation from that article: "So called factory methods are another valid use case for static methods.". And static `factory methods` does *not* couple class with it's colloborators. Using this methods `inside` collaborators class couples it. But that's rather a `Dependency Injection` violation. So, I can't agree with you, static `factory methods` does not violate SRP by themselves. They create the opportunity for such violation, but code that actually violate that principle most likely would violate it with separate `Factory` class as well.

Comment: @J0HN Read that again please. Kore says *"Since the factory methods, just like all your class constructors, are used in your DIC anyways, this won't create a static dependency of any kind"*. If you do not use a Dependency Injection Container (DIC), then you *will* introduce coupling between collaborators. The only way not to tight couple a static method is by using `$className::fn()`. The moment you use `Classname::fn()`, you coupled. Your example doesnt mention anything about using a DIC. And it doesnt change that factory methods on the business object do violate SRP.

Comment: @Gordon, in general you are right and I'm not arguing that. But DI is far beyound the question asked. And actually, IMHO, introducing the `Factory` for that single object in order to follow the SRP is just too much. I've said it before, if there is already a `Factory` - those methods for sure belongs to it. But if there isn't, the `Factory` will just not pay for itself. It might be a good starting responsibilities for the `Factory`, but the need for the `Factory` should be evaluated before creating it.

Comment: @J0HN well, for not argueing you argued a lot ;) We will have to agree to disagree now though. I dont think it's *too much* to introduce a Factory. The benefit of not violating SRP and DIP far outweighs the few lines of additional code it takes to create and use it. I agree you should evaluate a Pattern before using it, but imo, when looking at the OP's usecase, the only conclusion can be to use a Factory.

Comment: @Gordon, deep in my soul I agree with your point, but "thought thrives on conflict", so I was just imitating devil's advocate :) Also, thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is fine. There is nothing wrong about how you have accomplished this.
You can avoid using an extra variable and write the following:

```
$this->populate_by_id($id_or_name)
```

instead of the following two lines:

```
$this->id = $id_or_name;
$this->populate_by_id($this->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, but I'd say this makes for a more clearer interface:

```
class user {
    public function __construct( $id ) {
        $this->load( $id );
    }

    public function load( $id ) {
        $this->populate_by_id( $id )
    }

    public function loadByName( $name ) {
        $this->populate_by_name( $name )
    }
}

$user1 = new user();
$user1->loadByName('Max');
$user2 = new user(123);
```

With this approach, you also have don't have the (theoratical) downside that you can't have numeric usernames.

Comment: True! The `$id` argument in the constructor should be optional.

Answer (score 0):

So a user can't be named 123? Do you catch that in your registration form? ;-) Since it's not clear, as an objective reader of that code, to see what the constructor does, I would change it.

Why don't you use a basic constructor which does less, and call the appropriate method (either `retreive_by_id()` or `retreive_by_name()` to retreive the user?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the part of the code to know wether to load by name or id, and not let my constructor handle this.

```
$oUser = new User();
$oUser->loadByName($sName);


$oAnotherUser = new User();
$oAnotherUser->loadById($iId);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe could roughly be an [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), but ActiveRecord has a couple of drawbacks and isnt a too clean pattern. If you dont know the pattern and its implications, dont use it. Have a look at [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) patterns instead.

Here is an easy example implementation:

```
class Users
{
    protected $users = array();
    protected $userTableDataGateway;
    protected $userFactory;

    public function __construct($userTableDataGateway, $userFactory)
    {
       $this->userTableDataGateway = $userTableDataGateway;
       $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        if(false === isset($this->users[$id])) {
            $userData = $this->userTableDataGateway->findById($id);
            $this->users[$id] = $this->userFactory->createById($id, $userData);
        }
        return $this->users[$id];
    }
    …
}
```

Now instead of doing things like

```
$jane = new User(123);
$john = new User('john');
```

and having the User class fetch the data, you create the Users collection once in your bootstrap:

```
$users = new Users(
    new UserTableDataGateway(
        new DbAdapter('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'tableName');
    ),
    new UserFactory
);
```

and whenever you need to load a user from your database you simply do

```
$jane = $users->findById(123);
$john = $users->findByName('john');
```

This has the added benefit that your classes are much more dedicated in their responsibilites. This will lead to more maintainable, testable and reusable code. See [SOLID](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) for details.

As for your specific piece of code: [avoid doing work in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Dont mix Business Logic with Query or Creation Logic (unless it's an ActiveRecord). Dont combine arguments. Use two arguments or make two methods instead.